# How to use a JDBC driver via PySpark on AWS Glue?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, aws-glue, mysql-connector

How to use a JDBC driver via PySpark on AWS Glue?

As I was studying, the steps needed to do it would be the following:

1 - Download jdbc driver with .jar extension

2 - Save to an S3 bucket

3 - In the Glue script, enter the path to the driver using one of the following commands:

`[opção 1]  sc.addPyFile("S3://caminho para o driver no s3/mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar")           [opção 2]  spark._jsc.addJar("S3://caminho para o driver no s3/mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar")`

Since I was using an interactive session with the Jupter notebook within Glue, I also identified that I could use the %extra__jar magic command to insert  the driver path.  Locally I created a container using an image from the Glue environment, but locally the error returned is the following:

`"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"`

In the Glue the erro is:

`Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o103.load. : com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure`

4 - The way I'm trying to use the driver is through spark.read, as follows:

```
 spark.read \
      .format("jdbc") \
      .option("url", f"jdbc:mysql://{host}/?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull") \
      .option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") \
      .option("dbtable", f"({sql}) t") \
      .option("user", user) \
      .option("password", pwd) \
      .option("fetchsize", "1000") \
      .load()
```

I also tried to use it to create the session, but without success either:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \ 
                    .appName('SparkByExamples.com') \
                    .config("spark.jars", "mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar") \
                    .getOrCreate()
```

The errors mentioned in (3) occur after trying to use spark.read, before that there are no errors. I also tried using `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` as I saw it being suggested in another source, but always without success.

NOTE:

I know that it is possible to use native connectors in Glue through the platform's own graphical interface, but there you need to specify the database you want to access, but I want to access several databases and so I don't believe that this connection is an option , even because it seems to me that I can't use it other than using it to create dynamic frames instead of dataFrames. I don't know if after downloading the driver I should do something else like install it or something. Because in all the cases mentioned I am just executing the steps I mentioned.

Comment: Have you tried looking into using Glue DynamicFrames to read from your MySQL instance? It will be much simpler and you can convert DynamicFrame to DataFrame for further spark processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload the required JAR files in an S3 Bucket. And then, specify path to the JAR file in `Dependent JARs path` option in `Advanced properties` section of `Job Details`

Like this:
[image]

Also, do checkout this document on [Connection types and options for ETL in AWS Glue for Spark](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect.html). This is a better approach.